# Jenkins artifacts corrupted when copied

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm setting up a Jenkins declarative pipeline, where I need to copy an artifact from a different job. The artifact is of substantial size, 10.8 M, and seems to get corrupted when copied. I save the copied artifact again as an artifact in the second job and see the size as 10.78 M. Is there any reason for this behaviour or ways to avoid it?

The resulting code from the pipeline seems corrupted and a byte-by-byte comparison reveals differences between the artifact in the first and second jobs.

I use the Copy Artifact Plugin for Jenkins like so:

```
step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
projectName: 'First_Job',
filter: '**/*.rbf',
fingerprintArtifacts: true,
target: '.',
])
```

And I save the artifact for the second time like this:

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'My_Artifact.rbf', fingerprint: true
```

The artifact is copied and renamed on the system using a `bat` script between copying to the second job and archiving again.

Comment: alternatively you could use [robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx). I do it since .. well with Plug-Ins you never know ;)

Answer (score 1):

After digging around on the second build machine, I've found that the problem was a 'bug' in the Copy Artifact plugin. The copied artifact wasn't being cleaned up correctly after each build and the plugin doesn't overwrite the previous artifact, nor does it give a message saying it can't overwrite a file.

This gave the appearance of a successful copy while the pipeline used the old artifact.